# didPickDocumentsAtURLs delegate is not getting called for UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to use UIDocumentPickerViewController and need to target the app for iOS 11.0 and above. I am testing in simulator for iOS version 11.0, 12.0 and 13.4
The delegate method didPickDocumentsAtURLs in not called on 11.0 and 12.0 however it is called on 13.4 version of iOS. The documentPickerWasCancelled is called in all cases.

Here is a smallest code that can reproduce the issue. I have a main view with only one button and button tap handler is defined below.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller
didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)urls {
}

- (void)documentPickerWasCancelled:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller {
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

    documentPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Update: This is getting called for iCloud drive files but not for the local files.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I mean, isn't there anything else in your code which can cause this behavior? I copy & pasted your code, did add some `NSLog`s and both methods (`didPickDocumentsAtURLs`, `documentPickerWasCancelled`) are called on 11.4, 12.4 & 13.5.

Comment: I have nothing else in my project. It is clean project created by xcode. Not sure if the xocde version would matter. What xcode version did you try on? I am on 11.4.1
Going to upgrade the xcode to 11.5 and see

Comment: Upgraded the xcode to 11.5 and reinstalled the old simulators. Still same behavior. It works on iOS 13 but not on older. 
Is there any setting required in info.plist file?

Comment: Update: I am able to import from iCloud i.e. didPickDocumentsAtURLs is called for iCloud drive files but not for local (on device) files

Comment: I just tested it and you're right. Delegate method gets called for iCloud Drive files, but it doesn't get called for files coming from _On My iPhone_ source (local files). Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix this. It can also be a simulator problem only. I'd try this on a real device. I also tried to research this issue and I've found couple of people with the same symptoms (SO, Apple Forums), but there's no solution, just questions, ...